# SecurityErrorEvent in jwplayer from local

Tags: flash, jwplayer, crossdomain.xml, jwplayer6

I have strange error with jwplayer, when I publish video from their site, in preview all works fine with url  - http://qaq.ngrok.com/video/advice/53d8f2145a2b89830479d8e2/video.m3u8

But when I copy code after preview, and run it from local, or from same qaq.ngrok.com domain, it shows me error:

```
 "[SecurityErrorEvent type='securityError' bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text='Error #2048'".
```

Comment: Are you running from your local C drive? You need to at least have the player running in a local web server for it to function properly.If you can provide a link to where it is not working on your site though, we can look into it further.

Comment: http://qaq1.ngrok.com/html.html here's an example

Comment: ok I found where's the problem, in my playlist file, urls are https, but I trying to run player from http, thanks :)

Comment: Glad you got it, np :)